# How many worker threads should be used for concurrent API calls?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, cpu-cores

On the API that I am working a 
GET request to `https://example.com/api/projects/8124` end-point returns a JSON response like

```
{
    "project_name": "Program 1",
    "project_leader": "https://example.com/api/users/324",
    "tech_area": "https://example.com/api/tech_areas/4323",
    "submission_data": "2010-06-15"
}
```

I am interested in the actual value of `project_leader`, `tech_area` i.e their names so I am doing 2 more API calls for each project.

Currently, I am dealing with about 700+ projects so there are a total of **1400+ API calls.**

The API response time is about 500ms. Doing this with a single thread, it takes me about 10+ minutes, so I switched to the multithreaded solution.

I am using 'ThreadPoolExecuter' in python with **250 worker threads**.

**Question:**

1. What should be the correct number of worker threads that I should be using, and how do I decide that?
2. How does the number of threads in my application relate to threads or cores in my CPU.

I appreciate any insights on this. Thanks.

Comment: Test it.  Halve the number of threads, double the number of threads - what happens to your performance?

Comment: HI @MartinJames. I started out with 50 threads the timing was 270 secs. It improved as I went to 100, 150. Then I saw no change when I did it 300 and 500 and the best timing I got was 90 secs. I just wanted to confirm is this normal to use this number of threads?

Comment: It's normal if it works.:)   Sounds like 150 threads maxed out the available I/O and so further threads just resulted in more blocked threads.  You could make the number of threads a command-line parameter or even make the number of threads a property that can be changed during runtime, so allowing users to 'tune' their systems:)